# How to start enumerate counting at 2 instead of 1?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I want to start my enumitem counter at 2 instead of 1, but I do not know how. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{mycount} \renewcommand{\themycount}{\arabic{mycount}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\stepcounter{mycount}}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\themycount.\arabic*,ref=\themycount.\arabic*)}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Should be 2.1.
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Should be 3.1.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood what you want, but you just need to set your `mycount` counter to 1 in your preamble. And you don't need to use `\AtBeginEnvironment` since `enumitem` has a `before` key for injecting this sort of code. `enumitem` also has a `start` key which can be used to start any list at any number without manually incrementing the counter, but in your case that doesn't seem to be what you need.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{mycount} \renewcommand{\themycount}{\arabic{mycount}}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\themycount.\arabic*,
   ref=\themycount.\arabic*),
   before=\refstepcounter{mycount}}
\setcounter{mycount}{1}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Should be 2.1.
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Should be 3.1.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]